# Numerical vs. algorithmic methods

Tags: algorithm, optimization, methods, numerical-methods

In the book I am currently reading, there is a distinction made between deterministic numerical methods (e.g. gradient-based: Newton's method, gradient-free: Nelder-Mead) and algorithmic methods (e.g. exact methods: exhaustive search, heuristic methods: greedy search) for optimization.

I cannot really understand the difference that has been made. If you are given a new method and want to classify it as numerical or algorithmic method, what are you looking for in order to categorize it?

Earlier in the literature it was roughly defined that an algorithm = step-by-step instructions to solve a problem. Is that not true for every numerical method as well? Aren't they in the end algorithms too? Maybe the rough definition is missing some important point here...

I would be interested in how computer scientists think about it and how the distinction is made.

Comment: It's fuzzy and the context / background might be importent, for me: One is about reasoning of numeric quantities (usually infinite cardinality like the reals). The other is about discrete / countable entities. This imho touches *continuous vs. discrete-optimization*. The latter usually is needed when *if-else like decisions* are needed. Algorithms can follow this: e.g. Linear-Programming. An interior-point method based lp-solver is a numerical-methods as it's all about hessian-based steps in cont-space. The simplex-algorithm is algorithmic/*combinatorial* as it has some if-else characteristic.

Comment: @sascha please make that an answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not involve a specific/concrete programming problem. It looks like cs.stackexchange.com would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerical methods are definitely also a category of algorithms. Even stochastic methods like Monte Carlo approximations using just a bunch of random samples are in the end algorithms.

To my knowledge the conventional distinction is rather between **numerical** and **analytical** approaches, see for example also in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935405/what-s-the-difference-between-analytical-and-numerical-approaches-to-problems.